# Power Apps - Change dropdown to combo box

Tags: powerapp

I have a dropdown with a list with this in the items

`Distinct([@'second list'],'Control Title')`

I want to make this a combo box so a user can search instead of going through a dropdown with many values.

So 1) Can this be converted into a combo box somehow? It is not a "Person" field so it is not exactly searchable.

OR

2. Can a combobox be added and then linked to this dropdown? Ie so a user searches a combo box and then it is linked to my dropdown?

Thanks.

Edit - including image

[image]

Comment: You can hide/delete dropdown control and add combobox control instead of it. Set combobox control properties like items, DefaultSelectedItems, DisplayFields, etc. accordingly.

Comment: But the dropdown needs to get the value from the combo box. How can it do this? As the dropdown field is what i need to be submitted in my sharepoint list.

Comment: Are you using SP list form or canvas app? You can update SP list values from combo box as well. If you are using form control, you have to set the `Update` property of data card to values from combo box control.

Comment: SP list..   The dropdown is linked to a field in the SP list. The combo box I inserted it just on the edit screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both options are feasible, the easiest way would be to convert your existing dropdown list into a combo box. You can achieve this by setting the `"Input control"` property of the combo box to `"Dropdown"` in the properties menu. Then, navigate to the "Data" tab of the combo box properties and set the "Items" property to the following formula:

```
Distinct([@'second list'],'Control Title')
```

This formula will populate the combo box with the same values from your original dropdown list.

If you want to make the combo box searchable, you can enable the `"Search"` property in the `"Advanced"` tab of the combo box properties. By enabling this feature, a search box will appear at the top of the combo box, allowing users to type in keywords to filter the list of values